# JS animation library using requestAnimationFrame with setTimeout as a fallback

Tags: javascript, animation, requestanimationframe

Is there a JavaScript animation library that uses requestAnimationFrame?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this TweenLite library by Jack Doyle. It's hight performance oriented (requestAnimationFrame and setTimeout fallback). I have a lot of experience with it and I often choose it over CSS animations!

http://www.greensock.com/v12/

It's recommended by [Chris Coyer](http://css-tricks.com/svg-animation-on-css-transforms/) and [Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/look-and-feel/animations/css-vs-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

There's Anim which uses requestAnimationFrame http://github.com/relay/anim/

Comment: I don't see it using requestAnimationFrame anywhere in the code.

Comment: https://github.com/relay/anim/blob/master/anim.js#L92 It's being de-referenced on line 92.

Comment: Oh, very interesting approach.